# output result to a file

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, duplicates

```
$outFile = "C:\PS logs\Outlook_autofill\test.csv"
$tests = Import-Csv -Header username,firstname,surname,pcname,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 $outFile |
sort -property @{Expression="username";Descending=$true}, @{Expression="pcname";Descending=$false} 
$tests[0]

for ($i=1; $i -le $tests.length -1; $i++)  
    {
    if ($tests[$i]."username" -eq $tests[$i-1]."username" -AND $tests[$i]."pcname" -eq $tests[$i-1]."pcname")
        {
        continue
        }
    else {$tests[$i]}
    }
```

I managed to download the code from a site on the Internet and get it working and it appears to do what I would like. However, I am unsure how to output it back into a CSV?
Would I put an output line in the same loop as the `continue`
thank you kindly for any help.

Comment: Hello, are you wanna rewrite existing csv file or create new csv?

Comment: You should first describe your problem and then give the code sample. No need to mention your name at the end of the question, because your name appears under your question.

Comment: `| Export-csv -path c:\ path -NoTypeInformation -Append`

Comment: thank you for all your responses, I am very grateful. I have been coding powershell on my own and trying to learn and your help is very inspiring. @Abdollah, thank for point that out,  I will leave my name out next time and put the description at the top.
 @ Vad, I need to rewrite the exiting file.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for that code, I will give it a go, am I to put that at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this construction right inside your loop to add each line to the file you need.

```
$NewLine = "{0},{1},{2}" -f $ValueForColumn1, $ValueForcolumn2, $ValueForcolumn3
Add-Content -Path $PathToFile -Value $NewLine
```